# No route matches {:controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

*I've read over 20 StackOverflow pieces (and plenty others across the web) on very similar issues and tried their solutions, but none of it has worked. Please help this beginner!*

*In particular, the solution I've found most often is*

```
form_for [@parent, @child] do |f|
```

*but it doesn't fix the error the way it did for other people.*

## Error:

*The error occurs at localhost:3000/locations/1/restaurants/new*

NoMethodError in Restaurants#new

Showing /app/views/restaurants/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
undefined method `restaurants_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb7ab89ea80>:0x007fb7aaadc3c0>
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for [@location, @restaurant] do |f| %>
2:   <% if @restaurant.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@restaurant.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this restaurant from being saved:</h2>
```

*I can't find any mention of* restaurants_path *in any of the app code, so I'm assuming it's some magical Rails default.*

## Code:

*I'm using* has_many/belongs_to *models: A location has many restaurants.*

config/routes.rb

```
  resources :locations do
    resources :restaurants
  end
```

$ rake routes

```
location_restaurants GET    /locations/:location_id/restaurants(.:format)          restaurants#index
                         POST   /locations/:location_id/restaurants(.:format)          restaurants#create
new_location_restaurant GET    /locations/:location_id/restaurants/new(.:format)      restaurants#new
edit_location_restaurant GET    /locations/:location_id/restaurants/:id/edit(.:format) restaurants#edit
location_restaurant GET    /locations/:location_id/restaurants/:id(.:format)      restaurants#show
                         PUT    /locations/:location_id/restaurants/:id(.:format)      restaurants#update
                         DELETE /locations/:location_id/restaurants/:id(.:format)      restaurants#destroy
```

app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @restaurant }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    @restaurant = @location.restaurants.create(params[:restaurant])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save
    format.html { redirect_to location_restaurants_path(@location), notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant, status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized a `@location`, which is required for your form (in the line `form_for [@location, @restaurant]`). Just add a line that looks it up (using `Location.find`) to your `new` action and then build `@restaurant` so that it is associated with the location:

```
def new
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
  @restaurant = @location.restaurants.build
  ...

end
```

Since you'll need `@location` for all your actions (including `edit`, which I assume must not be working either in your current code), it would make sense to put it into a separate method and then call it from a `before_filter`, i.e.:

```
before_filter :find_location

private

def find_location
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
end
```

Then you can also remove the line where you find the location in your `create` action (and from the `new` action).

Comment: There was a typo: `@location.restaurant.build` should be `@location.restaurants.build`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the way you are instantiating the `@restaurant` variable in the `new` action. Because it is nested under locations, you need to build it as such:

`@location = Location.find(params[:location_id])`
`@restaurant = @location.restaurants.new`